# Simultaneously extending the functionals of a subspace of a Banach space to the whole space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, duality

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$. If $\varphi\in Y^*$, then Hahn-Banach allows us to extend $\varphi$ to a $\tilde\varphi\in X^*$, such that $\|\tilde\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|$. This extension can happen in infinitely many ways, in general.

My question is the following: *Can we guarantee the existence of a bounded linear transformation*
$$
F : Y^*\to X^*, 
$$
*such that $F(\varphi)$ is an extension of $\varphi\in Y^*$ as a bounded linear functional on $X$?* (Preferably with $\|F\|=1$.)

First unsuccessful attempt: Define $F$ on a (Hamel) basis of $Y^*$, and then linearly extend to the whole of $Y^*$. But this $F$ is not necessarily bounded.

Comment: There are results available, when the extension is unique, e.g. in a Hilbert space or more general results can be found here http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1993289?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21103704449827. Of course, Hamel basis are not to be chosen in topological vector space, e.g. for Banach spaces one works with a Schauder basis.

Comment: Be careful, there exists Banach spaces which do not admit a Schauder Basis. The first examples are due to Enflo.

Comment: Having a Schauder basis still might not save you; see Bill Johnson's answer. Note that every Banach space $Y$ embeds isometrically into some $X=\ell^\infty(\Gamma)$, but it is relatively rare that $Y^\perp$ will be complemented in $X^*$.

Answer (score 8):

No.  Note that your condition is equivalent to having the dual to the short exact sequence

$Y\to X \to X/Y$

split, which is equivalent to having $Y^\perp$ complemented in $X^*$.